# TSM Can't Restore to Another Node

Tags: migration, backup-restoration, tsm

I have a server setup here which has been running for more than eight years.  The servers are starting to fail, so the ability to restore from backup is becoming critical.

I have a machine which has died.  When I go into **TSM Backup-Archive GUI** on another machine, I then go to `Utilities -> Access Other Node...`.  I put the node name of the dead node into the dialog box.  When I reenter the **Restore** screen, I can see the tree of files, but the tree is empty.

When I pick any one of the other servers, whether they are Windows, Linux or AIX, I am able to see the populated tree of backed up files for the local node.  I just can't retrieve the data for the dead node.  Is there anything that needs to be reconfigured to allow this access?  I've already reset the password, which didn't help.  Is there any way to extract the data from the TSM server itself?

I beg for quick help.  As you can imagine, this is a major production issue.  Thanks for reading.